# All kinds of Row Space of a matrix

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

For example, determine a basis for the row space of
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  -1&  1&  3& 2\\ 
 2&  -1&  1&  5& 1\\ 
 3&  -1&  1&  7& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  -1&  -1& -3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Reduce A to the row-echelon form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  -1&  1&  3& 2\\ 
 0&  1&  -1& -1& -3\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, the basis of  row space of A is $(1,-1,1,3,2)$, and $(0,1,-1,-1,-3)$

Since any row-echelon form of A is a basis for
its row space, so if we reduce A to the reduced row-echelon form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&  0&  2& -1\\ 
 0&  1&  -1& -1& -3\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
 so the basis of  row space of A can also be $(1,0,0,2,-1)$, and $(0,1,-1,-1,-3)$

I have three questions

1.Does the original rows $(1,-1,1,3,2)$, and $(2,-1,1,5,1)$ in A also form a basis for row space? Because I think I read from somewhere that "the pivot columns do not, necessarily, form a basis for column space. However, the cor
responding columns in the original matrix do", I 'm sure if the corresponding rows can also form a basis for row spaces

2. Why pivot columns do not, necessarily, form a basis for column space while pivot rows can forma a basis for row space?
3. How can I see the linear combinaton relationship in each rows in A without transposing A by making each row into column then do the usunal methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the original rows you give also form a basis for the row space.

To see that the pivot columns don't work, just look at an example, e.g., $$A=\pmatrix{1&1\cr1&1\cr}$$ has column space generated by $(1,1)$, while the reduced form $$\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&0\cr}$$ has column space generated by $(1,0)$. Each type of elementary row operation preserves the row space, but not necessarily the column space (think about it!).

What's wrong with transposing and then doing row reduction? I suppose you could do column reduction, instead, though I don't see what you gain.

Comment: does it mean that the only way to  tell the linear combination relationship between rows in a matrix is transpoing the matrix and then do row reduction and tell from the pivot cloumns , am I correct?

Comment: As I said, you could do column reduction.